# How to deal with missing values in jsonlite?

Tags: r, json, na, jsonlite

I am dealing with data from a repeated measure design. The data consists of 4 measurements, each measuring about 100 variables. One of these variables is a JSON-array containing the results of a reaction task. The structure of this array is basically like this: [[prime, answer, reaction time], [prime, answer, reaction time], ...]

Each array consists of about 80 trials. My aim is to convert this array to separate columns, so that it looks like the example below:

```
prime1    answer1     reaction_time1    prime2     answer2   reaction_time2 ...
picture8  2           2398              2          1         1856
picture8  1           798               1          2         712
...
```

When working with an example data set, I managed to convert the array to a dataframe using the following code:

```
reaction_data <- data.frame(example_data$ID, example_data$TP,
                       jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", example_data$reaction_raw))))
```

As mentioned above, I am now dealing with data from repeated measurements, arranged in a long-format. So, for each person `ID` I have four measurements `TP`, and ideally, a complete set of data for all of the 100 variables, including the JSON array. However, in reality, of course I am dealing with drop-outs and missing values. This means that also the JSON-array is missing for some cases. Pretending my JSON-array would consist of only 3 trials, my current dataframe looks more or less like the example data below (ignoring all the other variables):

```
ID       TP         reaction_raw
1        1          [[picture8, 2, 2398], [picture2, 1, 1856], [picture1, 1, 897]]
1        2          [[picture8, 1, 798], [picture2, 2, 712], [picture1, 1, 423]]
1        3          NA
1        4          [[picture8, 1, 1278], [picture2, 1, 1712], [picture1, 1, 902]]
2        1          [[picture8, 2, 2015], [picture2, 1, 3820], [picture1, 2, 2719]]
2        2          [[picture8, 2, 3219], [picture2, 2, 1920], [picture1, 1, 1298]]
2        3          NA
2        4          NA
3        1          [[picture8, 1, 209], [picture2, 1, 382], [picture1, 2, 891]]
3        2          NA
3        3          [[picture8, 2, 781], [picture2, 1, 291], [picture1, 1, 2039]]
3        4          NA
...
```

When running now my code, I get the following error message:

```
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^
```

I guess my code is not able to deal with the missing arrays. Does someone have an idea how to deal with this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Charlotte. Your strings aren't valid json. Are the terms `picture8`, `picture2` and `picture1` quoted in your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are missing quotation marks in the example (otherwise the parser wouldn't get past the first occurence of `picture8` without complaining), the way to handle this is to add an appropriately formatted json string that will translate as `NA` entries in the desired data structure.

So, for example, assuming your data looked like this:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>       ID    TP reaction_raw                                                     
#>    <int> <int> <chr>                                                            
#>  1     1     1 "[[\"picture8\", 2, 2398], [\"picture2\", 1, 1856], [\"picture1\~
#>  2     1     2 "[[\"picture8\", 1, 798], [\"picture2\", 2, 712], [\"picture1\",~
#>  3     1     3  <NA>                                                            
#>  4     1     4 "[[\"picture8\", 1, 1278], [\"picture2\", 1, 1712], [\"picture1\~
#>  5     2     1 "[[\"picture8\", 2, 2015], [\"picture2\", 1, 3820], [\"picture1\~
#>  6     2     2 "[[\"picture8\", 2, 3219], [\"picture2\", 2, 1920], [\"picture1\~
#>  7     2     3  <NA>                                                            
#>  8     2     4  <NA>                                                            
#>  9     3     1 "[[\"picture8\", 1, 209], [\"picture2\", 1, 382], [\"picture1\",~
#> 10     3     2  <NA>                                                            
#> 11     3     3 "[[\"picture8\", 2, 781], [\"picture2\", 1, 291], [\"picture1\",~
#> 12     3     4  <NA>
```

Then you could write a json with `null` arguments for the missing values and write this in where `reaction_raw` is `NA`:

```
nulljson <- "[[\"picture8\", null, null], 
              [\"picture2\", null, null], 
              [\"picture1\", null, null]]"

df$reaction_raw[is.na(df$reaction_raw)] <- nulljson
```

Now you can shape the json into separate columns...

```r
parser        <- function(x) as.vector(t(jsonlite::fromJSON(x)))
result_matrix <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$reaction_raw, parser))
result_df     <- as.data.frame(result_matrix)
col_names     <- c("prime", "answer", "reaction_time")
col_names     <- paste0(col_names, rep(1:3, each = ncol(result_df)/3))
result_df     <- setNames(result_df,col_names)
```

...and join them to your main data frame:

```
cbind(df[1:2], result_df)
#>    ID TP   prime1 answer1 reaction_time1   prime2 answer2 reaction_time2
#> 1   1  1 picture8       2           2398 picture2       1           1856
#> 2   1  2 picture8       1            798 picture2       2            712
#> 3   1  3 picture8    <NA>           <NA> picture2    <NA>           <NA>
#> 4   1  4 picture8       1           1278 picture2       1           1712
#> 5   2  1 picture8       2           2015 picture2       1           3820
#> 6   2  2 picture8       2           3219 picture2       2           1920
#> 7   2  3 picture8    <NA>           <NA> picture2    <NA>           <NA>
#> 8   2  4 picture8    <NA>           <NA> picture2    <NA>           <NA>
#> 9   3  1 picture8       1            209 picture2       1            382
#> 10  3  2 picture8    <NA>           <NA> picture2    <NA>           <NA>
#> 11  3  3 picture8       2            781 picture2       1            291
#> 12  3  4 picture8    <NA>           <NA> picture2    <NA>           <NA>
#>      prime3 answer3 reaction_time3
#> 1  picture1       1            897
#> 2  picture1       1            423
#> 3  picture1    <NA>           <NA>
#> 4  picture1       1            902
#> 5  picture1       2           2719
#> 6  picture1       1           1298
#> 7  picture1    <NA>           <NA>
#> 8  picture1    <NA>           <NA>
#> 9  picture1       2            891
#> 10 picture1    <NA>           <NA>
#> 11 picture1       1           2039
#> 12 picture1    <NA>           <NA>
```

---

**Data used**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), TP = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), reaction_raw = c(
"[[\"picture8\", 2, 2398], [\"picture2\", 1, 1856], [\"picture1\", 1, 897]]", 
"[[\"picture8\", 1, 798], [\"picture2\", 2, 712], [\"picture1\", 1, 423]]", 
NA, "[[\"picture8\", 1, 1278], [\"picture2\", 1, 1712], [\"picture1\", 1, 902]]", 
"[[\"picture8\", 2, 2015], [\"picture2\", 1, 3820], [\"picture1\", 2, 2719]]", 
"[[\"picture8\", 2, 3219], [\"picture2\", 2, 1920], [\"picture1\", 1, 1298]]", 
NA, NA, "[[\"picture8\", 1, 209], [\"picture2\", 1, 382], [\"picture1\", 2, 891]]", 
NA, "[[\"picture8\", 2, 781], [\"picture2\", 1, 291], [\"picture1\", 1, 2039]]", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>